# How to read multiple text files into a single RDD?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to read a bunch of text files from a hdfs location and perform mapping on it in an iteration using spark.

`JavaRDD<String> records = ctx.textFile(args[1], 1);` is capable of reading only one file at a time.

I want to read more than one file and process them as a single RDD. How?

Answer (score 312, accepted):

You can specify whole directories, use wildcards and even CSV of directories and wildcards.  E.g.:

```
sc.textFile("/my/dir1,/my/paths/part-00[0-5]*,/another/dir,/a/specific/file")
```

As Nick Chammas points out this is an exposure of Hadoop's [`FileInputFormat`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html) and therefore this also works with Hadoop (and Scalding).

Comment: Yep, this is the most convenient way to open multiple files as a single RDD. The API here is just an exposure of [Hadoop's FileInputFormat API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.html), so all the same `Path` options apply.

Comment: `sc.wholeTextFiles` is handy for data which is not line-delimited

Comment: It is weird though that if you do this and specify parallelism, say `sc.textFile(multipleCommaSeparatedDirs,320)` it leads to `19430` total tasks instead of `320` ... it behaves like `union` which also leads to insane number of tasks from very low parallelism

Comment: I finally found how this evil file pattern matching works http://stackoverflow.com/a/33917492/306488 so I don't need to comma delimit anymore

Comment: @femibyte I don't think so, though I don't know why you would want to know the file name in any situation other than for `wholeTextFiles`.  What is your use case?  I can think of a workaround provided you use the same number of partitions as files ...

Comment: I'm working through some Amplab tutorials and they reformatted the files so each line of the RDD contains the filename. I don't have access to their AWS cluster, so I wanted 2 do the same w/o having to go through the pain for uncompressing a gzipped file, and rewriting each line. It seems like that's what I have to do thanks.

Comment: @femibyteuse below API to read the data from gzipped files  sc.textFile("/my/directory/*.gz") and also  your statement "so I can append it to the lines in the RDD"  even if you append to existing RDD, ultimately spark will create new RDD as RDDs are resilient.

Comment: The links to Hadoop's FileInputFormat API docs are now broken; the closest thing I've found in the most recent Hadoop docs is: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-

Answer (score 35):

Use `union` as follows:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(...)
val r1 = sc.textFile("xxx1")
val r2 = sc.textFile("xxx2")
...
val rdds = Seq(r1, r2, ...)
val bigRdd = sc.union(rdds)
```

Then the `bigRdd` is the RDD with all files.

Comment: Thank you cloud, that way I can I read all the files I want, but one! But still, I have to write a lot of things...

Answer (score 31):

You can use a single textFile call to read multiple files. Scala:

```
sc.textFile(','.join(files))
```

Comment: and identical python syntax

Comment: I think that is _only_ python syntax. The Scala equivalent would be `sc.textFile(files.mkString(","))`

Answer (score 9):

You can use this

First You can get a Buffer/List of S3 Paths :

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import java.util.ArrayList
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectListing
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest

def listFiles(s3_bucket:String, base_prefix : String) = {
    var files = new ArrayList[String]

    //S3 Client and List Object Request
    var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
    var objectListing: ObjectListing = null;
    var listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest();

    //Your S3 Bucket
    listObjectsRequest.setBucketName(s3_bucket)

    //Your Folder path or Prefix
    listObjectsRequest.setPrefix(base_prefix)

    //Adding s3:// to the paths and adding to a list
    do {
      objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
      for (objectSummary <- objectListing.getObjectSummaries().asScala) {
        files.add("s3://" + s3_bucket + "/" + objectSummary.getKey());
      }
      listObjectsRequest.setMarker(objectListing.getNextMarker());
    } while (objectListing.isTruncated());

    //Removing Base Directory Name
    files.remove(0)

    //Creating a Scala List for same
    files.asScala
  }
```

Now Pass this List object to the following piece of code, note : sc is an object of SQLContext

```
var df: DataFrame = null;
  for (file <- files) {
    val fileDf= sc.textFile(file)
    if (df!= null) {
      df= df.unionAll(fileDf)
    } else {
      df= fileDf
    }
  }
```

Now you got a final Unified RDD i.e. df

Optional, And You can also repartition it in a single BigRDD

```
val files = sc.textFile(filename, 1).repartition(1)
```

Repartitioning always works :D

Comment: Doesn't this mean the file list has to be relatively small? Not millions of files.

Comment: Can we parallelize the operation of reading the listed files? something like sc.parallelize ?

Comment: @MathieuLongtin : If you can apply partition discovery to your Spark code then it'll be great else you need to do the same like it. I used to open 10k files in approx a min.

Comment: @lazywiz If you dont want to create a single rdd then just remove the repartition action.

Answer (score 3):

In PySpark, I have found an additional useful way to parse files. Perhaps there is an equivalent in Scala, but I am not comfortable enough coming up with a working translation. It is, in effect, a textFile call with the addition of labels (in the below example the key = filename, value = 1 line from file).

**"Labeled" textFile**

input:

```
import glob
from pyspark import SparkContext
SparkContext.stop(sc)
sc = SparkContext("local","example") # if running locally
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

for filename in glob.glob(Data_File + "/*"):
    Spark_Full += sc.textFile(filename).keyBy(lambda x: filename)
```

output: array with each entry containing a tuple using filename-as-key and with value = each line of file. (Technically, using this method you can also use a different key besides the actual filepath name- perhaps a hashing representation to save on memory). ie.

```
[('/home/folder_with_text_files/file1.txt', 'file1_contents_line1'),
 ('/home/folder_with_text_files/file1.txt', 'file1_contents_line2'),
 ('/home/folder_with_text_files/file1.txt', 'file1_contents_line3'),
 ('/home/folder_with_text_files/file2.txt', 'file2_contents_line1'),
  ...]
```

---

You can also recombine either as a list of lines:

`Spark_Full.groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1]))).collect()`

```
[('/home/folder_with_text_files/file1.txt', ['file1_contents_line1', 'file1_contents_line2','file1_contents_line3']),
 ('/home/folder_with_text_files/file2.txt', ['file2_contents_line1'])]
```

Or recombine entire files back to single strings (in this example the result is the same as what you get from wholeTextFiles, but with the string "file:" stripped from the filepathing.):

`Spark_Full.groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0], ' '.join(list(x[1])))).collect()`

Comment: When I ran this line of code - `Spark_Full += sc.textFile(filename).keyBy(lambda x: filename) ` I got the error i.e. `TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable`. My understanding is that, that line creates an RDD which is immutable, so I was wondering how you were able to append it to another variable?

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
JavaRDD<String , String> records = sc.wholeTextFiles("path of your directory")
```

here you will get the path of your file and content of that file. so you can perform any action of a whole file at a time that saves the overhead

Answer (score 1):

There is a straight forward clean solution available. Use the wholeTextFiles() method. This will take a directory and forms a key value pair. The returned RDD will be a pair RDD. 
Find below the description from [Spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html):

> SparkContext.wholeTextFiles lets you read a directory containing multiple small text files, and returns each of them as (filename, content) pairs. This is in contrast with textFile, which would return one record per line in each file

Answer (score 1):

All answers are correct with `sc.textFile`

I was just wondering why not [`wholeTextFiles`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#wholeTextFiles-java.lang.String-int-) For example, in this case...

```
val minPartitions = 2
val path = "/pathtohdfs"
    sc.wholeTextFiles(path,minPartitions)
      .flatMap{case (path, text) 
    ...
```

one limitation is that, we have to load small files otherwise performance will be bad and may lead to OOM.

**Note :**

- The wholefile should fit in to memory
- Good for file formats that are NOT splittable by line... such as XML files

Further reference to [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47130982/647053)

Comment: or just `sc.wholeTextFiles(folder).flatMap...`

Comment: sc.wholeTextFiles(“/path/to/dir”)

Answer (score -1):

**TRY THIS** 
Interface used to write a DataFrame to external storage systems (e.g. file systems, key-value stores, etc). Use DataFrame.write() to access this.

New in version 1.4.

csv(path, mode=None, compression=None, sep=None, quote=None, escape=None, header=None, nullValue=None, escapeQuotes=None, quoteAll=None, dateFormat=None, timestampFormat=None)
Saves the content of the DataFrame in CSV format at the specified path.

Parameters: 
path – the path in any Hadoop supported file system
mode –
specifies the behavior of the save operation when data already exists.

append: Append contents of this DataFrame to existing data.
overwrite: Overwrite existing data.
ignore: Silently ignore this operation if data already exists.
error (default case): Throw an exception if data already exists.
compression – compression codec to use when saving to file. This can be one of the known case-insensitive shorten names (none, bzip2, gzip, lz4, snappy and deflate).
sep – sets the single character as a separator for each field and value. If None is set, it uses the default value, ,.
quote – sets the single character used for escaping quoted values where the separator can be part of the value. If None is set, it uses the default value, ". If you would like to turn off quotations, you need to set an empty string.
escape – sets the single character used for escaping quotes inside an already quoted value. If None is set, it uses the default value, \
escapeQuotes – A flag indicating whether values containing quotes should always be enclosed in quotes. If None is set, it uses the default value true, escaping all values containing a quote character.
quoteAll – A flag indicating whether all values should always be enclosed in quotes. If None is set, it uses the default value false, only escaping values containing a quote character.
header – writes the names of columns as the first line. If None is set, it uses the default value, false.
nullValue – sets the string representation of a null value. If None is set, it uses the default value, empty string.
dateFormat – sets the string that indicates a date format. Custom date formats follow the formats at java.text.SimpleDateFormat. This applies to date type. If None is set, it uses the default value value, yyyy-MM-dd.
timestampFormat – sets the string that indicates a timestamp format. Custom date formats follow the formats at java.text.SimpleDateFormat. This applies to timestamp type. If None is set, it uses the default value value, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ.

Answer (score -4):

```
rdd = textFile('/data/{1.txt,2.txt}')
```