# Spark: Task size is large when CombineTextInputFormat is used

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using CombineTextInputFormat to read many small files on Spark.

The Java code is as follows (I’ve written it as an utility function):

```
public static JavaRDD<String> combineTextFile(JavaSparkContext sc, String path, long maxSplitSize, boolean recursive)
{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.setLong(CombineTextInputFormat.SPLIT_MAXSIZE, maxSplitSize);
    if (recursive)
        conf.setBoolean(CombineTextInputFormat.INPUT_DIR_RECURSIVE, true);
    return
        sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, CombineTextInputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class, conf)
        .map(new Function<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>, String>()
        {
            @Override
            public String call(Tuple2<LongWritable, Text> tuple) throws Exception
            {
                return tuple._2().toString();
            }
        });
}
```

It works, but when the program runs, the following warning is printed:

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (159 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
```

The program reads about 3.5MB total, and the number of the files is 1234. The files are located in one directory.

Is this normal? Otherwise how can I get rid of this message?

My Spark version is 1.3.

The program runs in local mode.

Answer (score 0):

Independently from your problem, for which I do not have an answer, you might want to try a different method to process all files under a directory.

Spark supports processing not only single files, but entire directories in an easy way. If all your files were to be located, as in your case, in a single directory, the command `sc.textfile` could read every file inside of it by specifying the location, for example:

`sc.textfile("//my/folder/with/files");`

You can find more information about it in the following question: [How to read multiple text files into a single RDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029873/how-to-read-multiple-text-files-into-a-single-rdd)

Comment: It's true, but CombineTextInputFormat is way faster in my case. It took 9 secs to finish the job while sc.textFile() took 300 secs. (Yes, three hundred seconds)

Comment: I find it courious. What kind of operations are you performing on the dataset? Could you provide a sample of your app in order to test it myself?

Comment: Currently it's only a test on my PC. The problem is that currently the number of test input file is 1234, and the size of each file ranges from 1KB ~ 5KB which is pretty uncommon case for a hadoop application. The test input file will be way larger on a real system. So, it may not be a problem, but for the test I need CombineTextInputFormat.

Comment: I just tested a wordcount example with 1000 files (5KB each) and indeed, spark needed 160 seconds to finish the process (1 core). Not 300 seconds, but still much more than 9 seconds. As if you say, in the future you plan using much heavier datasets on a real system, however, it might not be an issue at all. I am sorry for not being able to help more here...