# How to use regex to include/exclude some input files in sc.textFile?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have attempted to filter out dates for specific files using Apache spark inside the file to RDD function `sc.textFile()`.

I have attempted to do the following:

```
sc.textFile("/user/Orders/201507(2[7-9]{1}|3[0-1]{1})*")
```

This should match the following:

```
/user/Orders/201507270010033.gz
/user/Orders/201507300060052.gz
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Looking at [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029873/how-to-read-multiple-text-files-into-a-single-rdd/24036343#24036343), it seems to use some form of glob syntax. It also reveals that the API is an exposure of Hadoop's `FileInputFormat`.

Searching reveals that paths supplied to `FileInputFormat`'s `addInputPath` or `setInputPath` ["may represent a file, a directory, or, by using glob, a collection of files and directories"](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=Wu_xeGdU4G8C&lpg=PA238&ots=i8wUUFRcZw&pg=PA236#v=onepage&q&f=false). Perhaps, `SparkContext` also uses those APIs to set the path.

The [syntax of the glob](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=Wu_xeGdU4G8C&lpg=PA238&ots=i8wUUFRcZw&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q&f=false) includes:

- `*` (match 0 or more character)
- `?` (match single character)
- `[ab]` (character class)
- `[^ab]` (negated character class)
- `[a-b]` (character range)
- `{a,b}` (alternation)
- `\c` (escape character)

Following the example in the accepted answer, it is possible to write your path as:

```
sc.textFile("/user/Orders/2015072[7-9]*,/user/Orders/2015073[0-1]*")
```

It's not clear how alternation syntax can be used here, since comma is used to delimit a list of paths (as shown above). According to [zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560062/zero323)'s comment, no escaping is necessary:

```
sc.textFile("/user/Orders/201507{2[7-9],3[0-1]}*")
```

Comment: Thanks, `{a,b}` for alternation, not what I was trying: `(a|b)`.

Comment: I tried to exclude files from a certain type , unfortunately, without success, can you please provide an example ?  some thing like *.^tmp