# Read files along with subdirectories from s3 using sc.textFile

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Trying to read the s3 data from java spark context:

```
"mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive", "true"
jsc.textFile(filePath);
```

It was working for me when I have only files insides hour folders:

```
s3://<year>/<month>/<day>/<hour>/<files>
jsc.textFile("s3://<year>/<month>/<day>");
```

Now, in S3 parallel to hour folder we may have new_folder as well

```
s3://<year>/<month>/<day>/<hour>/<files>
s3://<year>/<month>/<day>/<hour>/<new_folder>/<files>
```

Below code ignoring the files under new_folder

```
jsc.textFile("s3://<year>/<month>/<day>");
```

Tried with multiple regular expression, but my method "isPathExist" always return false

```
jsc.textFile("s3n://<year>/<month>/<day>/*/<regular_expression>");
```

Checked S3 path using below method, which returns false

```
private static boolean isPathExists(String folderPath, String bucket, String accessKey, String secret) {
    AWSCredentials cred = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secret);
    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(cred);
    ObjectListing objectListing = s3
            .listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucket).withPrefix(folderPath));
    return !objectListing.getObjectSummaries().isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting ? Are you getting any exception ? please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

If you want all subdirectories, then use two stars.

```
jsc.textFile("s3://<year>/<month>/<day>/**");
```

And files in those directories, one more star (I think)

```
jsc.textFile("s3://<year>/<month>/<day>/**/*");
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The only way I found is to list all the object using s3 API and then to give as input to spark the list of files.

Comment: @nicola my answer was based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782763/how-to-use-regex-to-include-exclude-some-input-files-in-sc-textfile