# How to read from multiple folders into single Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data inside a folder which is created every day.

Ex:Below is the format of the data folders present in AWS S3 for the whole year(2017) ie 365 folders

```
student_id=20170415
student_id=20170416
student_id=20170417
student_id=20170418
```

Each folder has multiple partitions of data in parquete format.

Now i would like to read only past 6 months(180 days/180 folders) of data and perform some logic on few columns.

How to read past 180 folders into a single Dataframe and i dont want to use unions (ie dont want to read each day data folder separately into each separate dataframe and union all later into giant Dataframe, nope i dont want to do that).

Im using Spark 2.0 & Scala

Answer (score 1):

You can make a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782763/how-to-use-regex-to-include-exclude-some-input-files-in-sc-textfile) for the directoryname something like below and use either SparkSession.read if you want only the content from the file or sparkContext.wholeTextFiles if you want a [K,V] pair like [filename,record]

```
val inputpath="/root/path/todir/2015{0[1-6]}[0-3]*"//reads only first six months folder(01-06)
spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(inputpath).toDF().show(1000) //Gives [K,V]
val data=spark.read.csv(inputpath).show(10000) //Gives only content
```

Both would result in a single DF. For sparkSession.read the size will be number of folders * number of lines in each file and for SparkContext.wholeTextFiles it would be number of folders * number of files