# Spark read multiple CSV file with header only in first file

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to read multiple CSV files from spark but the header is present only in the first file like:

file 1:

```
id, name
1, A
2, B
3, C
```

file 2:

```
4, D
5, E
6, F
```

PS: I want to use java APIs to do so

Answer (score 2):

You can use header=true and use inferSchema=true to get the correct data types from the file you have headers. Then get this schema type into to a StructType in Java and use that to import the other csv files without headers. This was tested in spark version 2.3.2

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;


    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("SimpleApp")
        .master("local")
        .getOrCreate();

  // Use this to get the headers automatically
    Dataset<Row> csvData = sparkSession.read()
       .format("csv")
       .option("header","true")
       .option("inferSchema","true")
       .load("C:\\MyData\\numData.csv");

    csvData.printSchema();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do something like the following

Scala solution:

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

val file1DF = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("file1.csv")

val schema = file1.schema

val file2DF = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("csv")
  .schema(schema)
  .load("file2.csv")
```

Java will be similar exception you'll want to use the [StructType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html) for the schema.

```
DataFrame file1DF = sqlContext.read()....;
StructType schema = file1DF.schema();
DataFrame file2DF = sqlContext.read()....schema(schema)....;
```

Comment: That would surely work but I'm looking for a generic solution that works for all files in a path. Also, I don't know the number of files in the path. So it won't be possible to read file individually.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you would know the name of the one file that has the header, if not all.
In that case, extending from the existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49728100/2438951), assuming name of file with the header is `h.csv` :

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

val file1DF = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("<path to folder>/h.csv")

val schema = file1.schema

val file2DF = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("csv")
  .schema(schema)
  .load("<path to folder>/{[^h],h[^.]}*.csv")
```

Now, the regex functionality provided is not too exquisite. But, I don't think the Spark [**DataFrameReader.load**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@load(paths:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) public api provides us any powerful way to exclude specific names.

More links to glob pattern that this API accepts are there @ this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31784292/2438951).

The internal API's from hadoop though seem to allow for a filtering (below image from relevant book section linked in above answer):

[image: PathFilter]

For your case you may want to name your file with header with a simplistic name, e.g. `h.csv` and the regex for second section in above code may have `{[^h],h[^.]}*.csv`, to include all files that don't start with `h` or if they start with `h` then the 2nd character is not `.`.

Comment: @Sandeep, did this help?