# spark read blob storage using wildcard

Tags: apache-spark, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to read Azure Blob storage files into spark using databricks. But I do not want to set a specific file or `*` for each level of nesting.

The standard: is `**/*/` not working. 
These work just fine:

```
val df = spark.read.format("avro").load("dbfs:/mnt/foo/my_file/0/2019/08/24/07/54/10.avro")
val df = spark.read.format("avro").load("dbfs:/mnt/foo/my_file/*/*/*/*/*/*")
```

fails with:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No Avro files found. If files don't have .avro extension, set ignoreExtension to true
```

for

```
val df = spark.read.format("avro").load("dbfs:/foo/my_file/test/**/*")
```

Answer (score 1):

Spark by default reads recursively down - so you only need to point at the root folder:

```
val df = spark.read.format("avro").load("dbfs:/foo/my_file/test/")
```

The path value is actually a regex.

`**` Does nothing

`*` will work - though it is usually done in the form `{*}`, known as globbing. This is worth a  read:[How to use regex to include/exclude some input files in sc.textFile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782763/how-to-use-regex-to-include-exclude-some-input-files-in-sc-textfile)

Comment: `val df = spark.read.format("avro").load("dbfs:/foo/my_file/test")` fails though and the trailing slash is mandatory.

Comment: Unfortunately, when trying it again it still fails.

Comment: Strange. I can even replicate this when not reading from blob storage using a local file system only. This problem only seems to be available when reading using format `avro`.