# Pyspark: how to read multiple csv from different folders?

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I have two folders `A` and `B`

`A` contains `file1.csv.gz` and `file2.csv.gz` and `B` contains `file2.csv.gz` and `file3.csv.gz`

I would like to read those files in a unique dataframe.

This what I am doing:

```
folders_to_read = ["A/*.csv.gz", "B/*.csv.gz"]
df = spark.read.format('csv').option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").\
  option("mode","DROPMALFORMED").load(i for i in folders_to_read)
```

But I get an error.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o200.load.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the path passed to pyspark needs to be a string. It would've been nice of pyspark to accept a list of strings but it doesn't seem to do so. You can get around it by using a regex. It seems to work on my local machine.

Folder structure:

```
$ cd /Users/username/Downloads/tmp
$ tree
.
├── A
│   └── a.csv.gz
└── B
    └── b.csv.gz
```

Code:

```py
x = spark.read.csv('/Users/username/Downloads/tmp/[AB]/*.csv.gz')
print(x)
DataFrame[_c0: string, _c1: string, _c2: string]
```

See this for more details on regex: 
[How to use regex to include/exclude some input files in sc.textFile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782763/how-to-use-regex-to-include-exclude-some-input-files-in-sc-textfile)