# Pyspark read file only if it exists

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have some parquet files in my `hdfs` directory `/dir1/dir2/`. The name of the files contain some timestamps but those are pretty random. For example, one file path is: `/dir1/dir2/2022-06-16-03-12-36-086.snappy.parquet`, where `2022, 06, 16` are year, month and date respectively and `03, 12, 36, 086` are hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds respectively.

Now, if I try to read all the files that have timestamp values between `2022-06-16-04-15-00-000` to `2022-06-16-05-15-00-000` using the following code:

```
paths = [f'/dir1/dir2/{tm.date()}-{tm.hour:02d}-{tm.minute:02d}-*' \
            for tm in pd.date_range('2022-06-16 04:15:00','2022-06-16 05:15:00', freq = 'min')]

df = spark.read.parquet(*paths)
```

Please note that the path does not exist for all the minutes or seconds or milliseconds.
Doing this, I am getting the following error -

```
AnalysisException: Path does not exist: /dir1/dir2/2022-06-16-04-23-*.snappy.parquet
```

To handle this error, I tried adding the following to my spark configuration:

```
("spark.sql.files.ignoreMissingFiles", "true")
```

But still, the error persists. How to read only the paths that do exist and not get error for the paths that don't exist?

Comment: can you check if the file exists before reading it? -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-without-exceptions

Comment: `spark.sql.files.ignoreMissingFiles` works only after the dataframe has been constructed, try following this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31784292/9477843) for your case

Comment: @samkart that answer would check files in the local dir, not in hdfs.