# spark: read multiple textfiles and spill out the first line of each file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to read multiple files (> 1000 files) and say only print out the first line for each file in spark?

I was reading the link
[How to read multiple text files into a single RDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029873/how-to-read-multiple-text-files-into-a-single-rdd)
which mentioned I can read in multiple files (say 3 files) in spark using the following syntax:

```
val fs = sc.textFile("a.txt,b.txt,c.txt")
```

But `fs` seems glue all the files together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use `HadoopFile` with `TextInputFormat`:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, Text}

val input: String = ???

val firstLines = sc.hadoopFile(
     input, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text])
  .flatMap {
    case (k, v) => if (k.get == 0) Seq(v.toString) else Seq.empty[String]
  }
```

Since keys of the `TextInputFormat` represent the offset of the beginning of the file for a given line you should get exactly what you want.

Comment: Zero, master of Spark, why not sc.wholeTextFiles()?

Comment: Mariano, zero, I have the same question, comparing to `sc.textFile` or `sc.wholeTextFiles`. Sorry I am not familiar with the `sc.hadoopFile` API....

Comment: @MarianoKamp My good man,  just to avoid follow-up questions starting with "what if data doesn't fit in the memory" :) Seriously though, from what I've seen so far `WholeTextFileInputFormat` usually shows significantly worse performance than the `TextInputFormat`. If you add possible memory issues on top of that it is really hard to justify `wholeTextFiles` here. Nice thing about this solution is that it doesn't require any configuration changes depending on a input.

Comment: @CarsonPun `textFile` is not applicable because it drops required information. You can use something like `sc.wholeTextFiles(input).map(_._2.takeWhile(_ != '\n'))` but I am not particularly fond of this solution.