# How to access this kind of data in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The data is stored in the following forms:

```
    data/file1_features.mat
    data/file1_labels.txt
    data/file2_features.mat
    data/file2_labels.txt
    ...
    data/file100_features.mat
    data/file100_labels.txt
```

Each `data/file*_features.mat` stores the features of some samples and each row is a sample. Each `data/file*_labels.txt` stores the labels of those samples and each row is a number (e.g., 1,2,3,...). In the whole 100 files, there are total about `80` million samples.

In `Spark`, how to access this data set?

I have checked the `spark-2.0.0-preview/examples/src/main/python/mllib/random_forest_classification_example.py`. It has the following lines:

```
    data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, 'data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt')
    (trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])
```

I run this example in `./bin/pyspark`, it shows the `data` object is a `PythonRDD`.

```
    PythonRDD[32] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48
```

The `data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt` is just one file. In my case, there are many files. Is there any `RDD` in `Spark` to handle this case conveniently? Does it need to merge all `100` files to one big file and process it as the example? I want to use the Spark engine to scale the data set (mean-std normalization or min-max normalization).

Comment: i see there are two type of file one with .mat extension and another with .txt extension...do you want to load all files into single rdd for processing? or want to load only txt/mat file?

Comment: @Shashi, yes, I want to load both types of data. The `*.mat` files are the features and the `*.txt` files are the labels. If I understand correctly, I think the data has been sharded. Thus, I wonder if we should write some simple interface to control the `*.mat` files (e.g. using h5py) to load them into numpy array, then feed them into the RDD in Spark. Then in the pyspark, we can use the RDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply point

```
   dir = "<path_to_data>/data"
   sc.textFile(dir)
```

Spark automatically picks up all of the files inside that directory

Comment: thank you! I also want to load the `*.mat` files. Maybe I should store the features into `*.txt` format. Your solution is a good start.

Comment: Does Spark already support reading `MATLAB` files? I think we should first convert the MATLAB matrix into `*.txt` format.

Comment: No - i did not "get" your meaning. Semantics of the file are up to you to provide. My point was only that all of the files - regardless of extension - would get sucked in. You will need to ensure compatibility of the format of the file and the intended usage by the spark worker app/code.

Comment: I think I didn't catch your ideas completely. I'm not familiar with Spark. I think I should get the basic knowledge about RDD. After searching, I find this post [http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/matfile-to-rdd/] and this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029873/how-to-read-multiple-text-files-into-a-single-rdd] might be related to this question. If I understand correctly, we should first read the batch data into memory, then merge them into a large RDD. But this seems to not right for RDD. With my limited information on Spark, I think RDD might be just some file keys in a map.

Comment: You do not need to worry about merging: spark takes care of it.  You should however do a pre-processing on the `.mat` files to get them into proper structure *before* the RDD operation.  That assumes they are few. If a lot you may consider a separate spark step that does the pre-processing of just the .mat files: but that in case you would need to have the .mat files in a separate directories from the .txt

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. Now I decide to first convert to the features (i.e., the `*.mat` files) into `*.txt` format. As the features contains multiple different features, I decide to save them into the following format `data/features/feature1/file1.txt`, `data/features/feature2/file1.txt`, ..., `data/features/feature1/file100.txt`. And for labels, I save them into `data/labels/file1.txt`, `data/labels/file2.txt`, ..., `data/labels/file100.txt`. Then I'll try the `sc.textFile('data/features/')` to load them into RDD.

Comment: But this will cost a lot of disk space to save those features because of the `*.txt` file format.

Comment: @mining  Spark is not matlab - so we need to make concessions. In any case disk space is doubtful to be the constrained resource here: cpu and/or ram are more likely, with networking the third likely liability.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks very much for your comments and suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

If you want load specific file type for processing then you can use regular expression for loading files into RDD.

dir = "data/*.txt"

sc.textFile(dir)

Spark will all files ending with txt extension.

Comment: thank you! I also want to load the `*.mat` files. Maybe I should store the features into `*.txt` format. Your solution is a good start.