# scala loop through multiple files in the path

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to `spark` and `scala`. I have below requirement. I need to process all the files under a path which have sub directories. I guess, I need to write a for-loop logic to process across all the files.

Below is the example of my case:

```
src/proj_fldr/dataset1/20170624/file1.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset1/20170624/file2.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset1/20170624/file3.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset1/20170625/file1.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset1/20170625/file2.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset1/20170625/file3.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset1/20170626/file1.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset1/20170626/file2.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset1/20170626/file3.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset2/20170624/file1.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset2/20170624/file2.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset2/20170624/file3.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset2/20170625/file1.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset2/20170625/file2.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset2/20170625/file3.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset2/20170626/file1.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset2/20170626/file2.txt
src/proj_fldr/dataset2/20170626/file3.txt
```

I need the code to iterate the files like
In src

```
   loop (proj_fldr
             loop(dataset
                      loop(datefolder
                                 loop(file1 then, file2....))))
```

Comment: Those files are on HDFS or local?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029873/how-to-read-multiple-text-files-into-a-single-rdd

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a regular file structure you can use the wildcard `*` when reading the files. You can do the following to read all the files into a single `RDD`:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("src/*/*/*/*.txt")
```

The result will be a `RDD[(String, String)]` with the path and the content in a tuple for each processed file.

To explicitly set if you want to use local or HDFS files you can append "hdfs://" or "file://" to the beginning of the path.