# How do I grab a value from a RDD in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have this code:

```
files = sc.wholeTextFiles ("file:///data/*/*/")
```

So, when I run the above command, I get this:

```
[('file:/data/file.txt',  'Message')]
```

How do I grab the 'Message' part and not the file name from this RDD in pyspark?

I have this code:

```
val message = files.map(x = > x._2)
```

but does not work.

Comment: The code you tried looks like scala, but you're asking about python. Direct translation of your code would be `message = files.map(lambda x, x[1])` but this seems like an XY problem. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: True, that looks like scala, but trying to get second tuple.  I don't need the file name, but just the message.  How would I write the scala code in pyspark?

Comment: I edited my original comment to add the python code.

Comment: I get a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" and it points to the first [ in the line. Can you help?

Comment: message = files.map(lambda x: x[1]).  This worked!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would do in scala

```
rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://nameservice1/user/me/test.txt")
rdd.collect.foreach(t=>println(t._2))
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [pyspark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.wholeTextFiles), `wholeTextFiles()`:

> Read a directory of text files from HDFS, a local file system (available on all nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI. Each file is read as a single record and returned in a key-value pair, where the key is the path of each file, the value is the content of each file.

So your code:

```
files = sc.wholeTextFiles ("file:///data/*/*/")
```

creates an `rdd` which contains records of the form:

```
(file_name,  file_contents)
```

Getting the contents of the files is then just a simple map operation to get the second element of this tuple:

```
message = files.map(lambda x: x[1])
```

`message` is now another `rdd` that contains only the file contents.

More relevant information about `wholeTextFiles()` and how it differs from `textFile()` can be found at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47129950/spark-textfile-vs-wholetextfiles).