# Spark: reading many files with read.csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to create a DataFrame from many small files located in the same directory. I plan to use `read.csv` from pyspark.sql. I've learned that in RDD world, `textFile` function is designed for reading small number of large files, whereas `wholeTextFiles` function is designed for reading a large number of small files (e.g. see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47129950/spark-textfile-vs-wholetextfiles)). **Does `read.csv` use `textFile` or `wholeTextFiles` under the hood?**

Comment: Best way to know is by reading the code. Best part is *Spark is open-source*!

Comment: I tried to read the source code of read.csv, so far I cannot find an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes thats possible**, *just give the path until the parent directory* as

```
df = spark.read.csv('path until the parent directory where the files are located')
```

And you should get *all the files read into one dataframe*. **If the files doesn't have the same number of csv rows then the number of columns is the one from the file which as the maximumn number of fields in a line**.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I know `read.csv` can read many files. The question is about internals of `read.csv`.