# adhoc multithreading and Spark

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark

I have a processing data pipeline including 3 methods ( let's say A(), B(), C() sequentially) for an input text file. But I have to repeat this pipeline for 10000 different files. I have used adhoc multithreading: create 10000 threads, and add them to threadPool...Now I switch to Spark to achieve this parallel. My question are:

1. If Spark can do better job, guide me basic steps please cause I'm new to Spark.
2. If I use adhoc multithreading, deploy it on cluster. How can i manage resource to allocate threads running equally among nodes.I'm new to HPC system too.

I hope I ask the right questions,  thanks !

Comment: where is the 10000 input files located? in HDFS? or local filesystem ?

Comment: local filesystem  and fit into memory (RAM)

Comment: Spark can read all files in a directory into a single RDD. See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24036343/864369

Comment: but then, how can I apply pipeline (includes 3 methods sequentially) ?Thanks Dan

Comment: The same way you would apply any function to an RDD. Please see Spark examples for specific information.